# How to keep the text selection in Terminal.app when typing

Tags: terminal, text

In Terminal.app, when I select some text and start typing again, the text selection is gone. I personally find this very annoying. Is there a way to make Terminal.app keep the selection when I type?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about the problem you're having? Because I opened up Terminal right now, selected some text, and it didn't disappear when I typed.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't the question precisely: The text itself stays there, but it's not selected any more when you type again.

Comment: There's probably no solution for this, but maybe [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) does it (haven't tried)?

Comment: I've actually seen this feature in iTerm on another guy's computer, which prompted me to ask. iTerm is very nice, but I've been using Terminal.app so much that I'd find it hard to switch.

Comment: Xterm keeps the selection in place when you type, but that's really an X11 behavior, not a Mac OS X behavior. Terminal generally follows the standards for Mac OS X applications. Other than being used to it, why do you want the selection to remain when typing? Why not just Copy the selected text to the clipboard, then type?

Comment: Terminal.app has the very nifty feature that you can use CMD+Shift+V to paste the selected text in the same tab without using the clipboard. You can achieve the same with a middle click (which is why I'm using Better Touch Tool to have a third button on my Magic Mouse). This is very useful as I usually just want to paste a file name or path that has been printed by a previous command as an argument on the command line.

Comment: If this behavior is important to you, tell Apple at <http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html> or file a bug report at <http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/> (requires a free developer account).

Answer (score 2):

So, I decided to give iTerm2 a spin after I hadn't looked at it in quite a few years. I have to admit that (with a little tweaking) it's actually a lot better than Terminal.app in many major and minor aspects. I have yet to find something that Terminal.app does better. So I guess that I'll just stick with iTerm2.