# How can I specify delimiters in Terminal for word and character selection before copying and pasting?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, terminal

I am new to Mac and still struggling to be productive with fewer clicks and keys...

When I use Terminal and click on a word, I would like the delimiter to be only space and not other characters like . _ / etc. I want these to be treated as part of the word. Then, I would like to be able to click on a word, be able to select the whole word and then copy and paste it to another place, say command line or into an editor etc. How do I achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Note: If you're specifically interested in selecting file and pathnames, Shift-Command-Double-Click will select pathnames (and URLs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com), where you can set the word delimiter in the preferences. I'm a recent convert myself and like it a lot better than Terminal.app. There's a special Terminal.app keyboard shortcut compatibility set to make switching easier.

[image: iTerm prefs window screenshot]

Comment: You're welcome! I was pointed to iTerm myself a few days ago: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/how-to-keep-the-text-selection-in-terminal-app-when-typing, and I haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 1):

For any new users coming to this question, the settings in iTerm are now done in two places :

1. General -> Selection : If you uncheck the "Double-click performs smart selection" option, you can specify delimiters in the last box.
2. Profiles -> Advanced -> Smart Selection : If you check the box in point 1, you can make changes here using regex.

[image]

Comment: This might work better as an edit to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Terminal application does not (yet) provide a way to configure this.

But [@Chris Page's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25281/how-can-i-specify-delimiters-in-terminal-for-word-and-character-selection-before/462231#comment28605_25281) is a good workaround and deserves a standalone answer:

> Note: If you're specifically interested in selecting file and pathnames, Shift-Command-Double-Click will select pathnames (and URLs).