# How to define the word boundary characters in terminal? double click on compound string in terminal command line is not highlighting entire string

Tags: terminal, command-line

on the osx command line in the default terminal application [ Version 2.11 (440) ] when terminal shows a string (so happens to be file fullpath)

```
/Users/scottstensland/src/foo/repos/live/test-scott/templates
```

and I wish to highlight the entire string (full pathname) I double click on any part of above string ... it only highlights the one word I am double clicking on

How to change terminal to highlight entire compound string interspersed with delimiters like the '/' character etc ...

normally I use Ubuntu which has below trick to define the word boundary characters in terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ word-char-exceptions  '@ms "-,.?%&#_+@~·/"'
```

where b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9 is just my profile as retrieved using

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default
```

so I believe I need the mac osx equivalent to above linux gsettings command

```
mac osx 11.4   Big Sur
mac mini M1  2020
chip  Apple M1
```

seems strange the default osx terminal is not optimized for software engineers ;-(

I am using bash shell on osx ... for reference I also use bash on linux

Comment: Have you tried using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com)?

Comment: What shell in Ubuntu? Which shell in macOS?  You could try triple-clicking to select the whole line. And *"not optimized for software engineers"* -- why should they, that's not their user base. Besides, every engineer wants something completely different! :-)  I haven't found this issue to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer I've found is no; it's not possible to configure for Terminal (see https://superuser.com/questions/125011/how-to-change-word-selection-separator-characters-in-mac-os-x)

### Workaround if you just want double click behavior in Terminal

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + double-click

### Workaround if you want more complex word delimiter control

Get iterm2 and use

`brew install iterm2`

That's got configurable word delimiters (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25283/23513)